# xcode UI Automation script runs fine on iPhone but fails on iPad

Tags: xcode, ipad, ui-automation

I have scripts in UI Automation which I do run on iPhone (real device and also SW simulator) and they are working fine. But when I run the scripts on iPad the script fails.

example:
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()["Empty list"].cells()["Tags:"].buttons()[0].tap();

this line works fine on iPhone but on iPad fails with the following error (script is trying to scrollToVisible - :/):

target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()["Empty list"].cells()["Tags:"].buttons()[0].scrollToVisible()
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()["Empty list"].cells()["Tags:"].buttons()[0] could not be tapped
Script threw an uncaught JavaScript error: target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()["Empty list"].cells()["Tags:"].buttons()[0] could not be tapped

any suggestions?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

you can use function,like a this one

```
//function
var _Model=function()
{
 var model=target.model();
 UIALogger.logMessage(model);
 return model;
}
//your main case
if(_Model()==='iPhone Simulator') 
{
 target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()["Empty list"].cells()["Tags:"].buttons()[0].tap();
}
else if(_Model()==='iPad Simulator') 
{ 
  //here you should write another way to tap Tags: Button
  //you can use record or logtree for getting element ID
} 
else 
{
 UIALogger.logFail("impossible to understand device type");
}
```